# Find and change HTML tag containing four-digit year while leaving text content intact

Tags: html, regex

I am looking for a four digit year between a `<p>` tag.  I then want to switch just the `<p>` tag to a `<h1>`.  I can find them with `<p>\d{4}</p>`, but how do I just replace the `<p></p>` with `<h1></h1>` and leave the year intact?

I have a locally saved html file that has 100+ years scattered in a large file. I need to switch the p tags out for h1 only on the year paragraphs, which are always p 4 digit year. I am going to use a text editor to do it then upload the file live.

The text editors I have are - Visual Studio, Sublime, Dreamweaver, and Notepad++.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in a text editor or maybe at run time?

Comment: @Gabriel Petrovay I have a locally saved html file that has 100+ years scattered in a large file.  I need to switch the p tags out for h1 only on the year paragraphs, which are always p 4 digit year.  I am going to use a text editor to do it then upload the file live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go if you use vim:

```
:%s/<p>\(\d\{4\}\)<\/p>/<h1>\1<\/h1>/g
```

The above expression [means](http://vimregex.com/#substitute): substitute (`s`) in the whole file (`%`) every occurrence (`g`) of `<p>(\d{4})</p>` with the first parenthesised expression `\1` surrounded by the `<h1>` tag (the special escaping of `(` and `{` is there just because vim wants it)

Or if you use other editors that accept regular expressions in searching and back references in replacement:

- search: `<p>(\d{4})</p>`
- replace with: `<h1>BR_1</h1>` where `BR_1` is the back reference notation in your editor (for example `$1`, `\1`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! Used the <p>(\d{4})</p> and need the $1 = <h1>$1</h1>!!!  Oh boy now I am unstoppable knowing this - lol.

Comment: Please note that this will fail if your `<p>year</p>` are not all on the same line, or if there is whitespace as in `<p> 2014 </p>`, or if your tags have other attributes like `<p class="copyright"> 2014 </p>`, or if there are other tags like `<p><strong>2014</strong></p>`, etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
if (regex match) {
    $("p").replaceWith('<h1>' + $("p").html() + '</h1>');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/oL0dcqnu/

Comment: this question is about doing it with nsregularexpression, not jQuery

Comment: @Michael Dziedzic if I where to use jQuery would I put the <p>\d{4}</p> in the regex match part?  I could try this then pull the HTML off the view source, but how do I enter in the regex?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. But as far as finding elements that match a given regex, check out; https://gist.github.com/jphase/8288780